# None of the above checkbox in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms, data-validation

I would like to create a multiple choice checkbox question in Google Forms with a 'None of the above' option and validate that if that option is selected, none of the other options are selected.

For example:

Choose your favourite fruits:

- Apple
- Pear
- Orange
- Banana
- None of the above

I can't see how to perform that sort of validation using the built-in validation options. Is there a way of performing such validation at data entry time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Google Forms there isn't a way to do that validation. The alternative is to change your questions, maybe use a multiple choice (radio button) asking do you like any of these fruits? . If the respondents select Yes send them to a checkbox question, if they select No, send the to another section or submit the form.

Comment: Pity, It complicates the survey with additional questions
None of the above options are common in other survey tools but I prefer using Google Forms